# Unnecessary padding in tableview cell iOS?

Tags: ios

I am developing an enterprise iOS application that uses splitview to display information. My split view, tabbars are all in place and seem to work fine. I have a tableview in the left pane of the splitview. The tableview has custom cells which contain an image view and several textview (removed textviews in the img) The height of the image view is same as the row height of the tableview and tableview cell. I wish to achieve a row height of 182 points. Even though I have kept all size same I see a padding on the left, top and bottom of the tableviewcell. In the tableview the cells thus appear separated by the background color. The tableview has no separators set. The only problem I see is that the image used inside the cell is only 168 points in height.

I did the same stuff in the detail view in the split view however now I see the table cells occupying the entire area designated to it. The image inside this detail view cell is only 160 points in height yet to I do not see that "padding" effect.

I have attached a sample screenshot, pls let me know where to fix it?[image: Split View with two table views]

Comment: Give me the code for that tableview. Either the cell height is wrong or the image does not match the cell..

Comment: yes that is what I said. The height of the image does not match with the row height (168 vs 182 points) on the left table view. However on the right side is a similar case the heights dont match (160 vs 182) yet there is no padding.

Comment: Post the code. Maybe it's a problem with the image or the frame of the image. Without code I can't really help you.